# Bicycle Pump: Dual (Schraeder/Presta) automatic valve stuck

Tags: maintenance, pump, presta, schrader

I got a pump with an head like this, and I use both the presta and the schraeder opening. The problem is that the automatic switching does not seem to work as well as it once did. It is pretty random where the air comes out, and most of the time it involves a lot of shaking and cursing before I can get my tires pumped up.

Can I fix this somehow? The pump was not cheap, and I would like to avoid getting a new one, though the hassle of getting air out of the correct hole is annoyinng.

This question is about a Pump Head, where the mechanism does work (air only comes out of one hole), but switches pretty randomly.

I want to get an answer if there is a solution without replacing the head, else i would order a new pump head.

[image: Dual Valve Pump Head]

Comment: This question was just asked. :)

Comment: On most high end pumps, you can replace the head.

Comment: You can replace the head on cheap pumps too. They sell cheap heads for just 2-3 Eurodollars on eBay.

Comment: If you've not-long bought it new, and it doesn't work right, then most countries have a mandated minimum warranty period of 12 months from date of sale.  Return it for replacement or refund.  If you bought it used, its a lemon and just replace the faulty pump head.   If its from Park Tool, contact their support department via their website.